# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com

Tags: git, github, git-push

Я сконировал репозиторий и в этой же папке сделал

```
$ git config --global user.name "your_github_username"
$ git config --global user.email "your_github_email"
$ git config -l
```

Сделал нужные изменения, git status:

```
    On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

При попытке сделать push.
После ввода имени логина и токкена возникает ошибка:

```
remote: Permission to projectgit.git denied to username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/projectgit.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Прошу помощи разобраться в чём дело.
Делал согласно данному описанию: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to
Но немного в другой последовательности и не кэшировал запись для сохранения токкена.

Comment: Опишите что именно вы делали и делаете и какие конкретно ошибки выдаются

Comment: Alexey Ten, описал, нужно ещё подробнее?

Comment: А как вы делаете push? По ссылке? 
Попробуйте поставить url для удаленного репо `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:your__url` А потом `push origin <branch>`

Comment: Max Watson, спасибо за мысль. Получилось сделать иначе. Заново пересоздал конфиги, скачал репозиторий и удалось выполнить push через IDE.

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/projectgit.git

Вы забыли между "github.com" и "projectgit.git" вставить имя пользователя, который является владельцем репозитория.

Для этого нужно удалить origin и создать  с новым URL.